# Can't get my bass to sound like Trax BT's "RAWWW" bassline

Tags: sound-design, synthesizer

The main bassline in this song, I'm pretty sure it's a sawtooth reese stacked with a kick, but I can't seem to get it to sound close or as nice.
It's the one at the very start of:
https://soundcloud.com/footwork-jungle/trax-bt-rawww-master

Any help on how to get it sounding that full ?

Comment: What have you got so far? How are you doing it?  I'm not hearing extreme evidence of reece [I had to look that up… it's just 2 detuned oscillators so it phase-shifts, for anyone else over 25;)) It sounds like it's being amped or comped into distortion, to brighten the top end, then side-chained off the kick.

Comment: Alex Reece was my first thought - That's near the start of "my era". [More pure-subby Jungle, though](https://youtu.be/oGG3_CJ60u8?t=40) (seems slow at the right speed - I still got the white label from the mid-90's). BUT ANYHOO - I don't think it's interacting with the kick (SC or whatever), It just has a slow attack to make room. And it is *extremely* wide. If it's not sounding right, it's probably not wide enough. Think putting one on each channel ([Think ABBA's extreme "double-tracking" method!](https://youtu.be/-crgQGdpZR0) - There's a cool reference). But we need to see what you've got.

Answer (score 0):

Use Serum or Vital

Add a bass and a lead

make sure that the wave of the bass changes throughout the envolope with a less distorted wave at the beginning and a more distorted wave at the end

here is a serum preset that I found that sounds similar
https://presetshare.com/preset/view?id=5520